# Inconsistency of visibility of data member in ordering class C++

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator, non-type-template-parameter

Since operator `<=>` was introduced in C++20, we first need to include `<compare>` before using (built-in, and defaulted).

However, I saw different implementations of each ordering (`std::weak_ordering`, `std::partial_ordering`, `std::strong_ordering`) in every implementation (maybe with a compiler), but the most notable one is the visibility of the **result** data after `operator<=>` comparison in which affects the qualification of being a **structural type** that could be used in non-type template parameter.

I've tested this code in 3 major library implementation: `libstdc++`, `libc++ (or libcxx)`, and `STL`:

```cpp
#include <compare>

template <auto>
struct nttp_test {};

constexpr void swallow(const auto&...) {}

int main() {

    swallow(
        nttp_test<(1 == 1)>{},
        nttp_test<(1 <=> 1)>{}
    );
    
}
```

Where:

- `STL` from `MSVC` passed. (https://godbolt.org/z/8r88sf4qv)
- `libstdc++` from `GCC` failed. (https://godbolt.org/z/Mbdzf48Pv)
- `libc++` from `Clang` also failed. (https://godbolt.org/z/9PxdTra3r)

It was revealed that only `STL` makes the data member `public` while the rest are `private` (I mean only the data member)

I'm being comfortable with `STL` because it makes the return value usable in `NTTP`, but in exchange, it exposes the data member to the public.

Which library implementation is correct? Or will it depend on every implementation?

Comment: The checks can, in the end, produce `true` or `false`. That can be deduced in class template `nttp_test`. So... this must be a class template with non-template types, and the two compilers are bugged with confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard defines the [ordering classes](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/cmp.categories.pre) in terms of "exposition only" members. These members are defined as `private`. Plus, there is no statement that any of these classes are structural types.

As such, you cannot assume that they are. So you cannot use them as NTTPs. An implementation may implement them as such, but the standard doesn't require it.

Now, maybe they should be. But they aren't. All of these implementations are equally valid.

What you *can* do is create parallel types that are structural types, and convert the standard library types to them. All of the members of these types are `constexpr`, so you can do that conversion without leaving constant expression evaluation.